# apache active mq console not starting

Tags: apache, activemq-classic

i have connected the Apache MQ broker service through java only by downloading active mq jars in dependency. but activemq web console not connecting. http://localhost/8161/admin . Please tell me is there any setting or configuration is need to connect ?

Comment: I am not an Apache MQ expert, but is port 8161 in Listen on your system (netstat -rn | grep LISTEN| grep 8161).  If not, some service or http server is not started.

Comment: no . it is not started

Comment: So you have to find in the MQ broker documentation how to start (and configure) the web console.

Comment: @KUMARK were you able to launch the web console?

Answer (score 0):

- Verify activemq.xml file from /conf . It must contain your correct IP for transport connectors.
- Check log4j.properties in /conf, update logging options to WARN at least, DEBUG if possible. Update File Logging Path.
- Run ./activemq start
- Let the system throw an exception.
- Check logs from the path you specified.
- Look for log exception in Stack Overlow or Google to get first analysis on error.

[More details](https://automateandtroubleshoot.000webhostapp.com/2019/12/how-to-install-and-bring-up-activemq-service-on-cygwin-linux)